# problem with writing a sql trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-workbench

I'm writing a SQL trigger to whenever update the (engage_step_user_response) table (response_json) column after updated. I need to increase no of retakes that I included same table as a column.
This is the trigger i have wrote. Can anyone please help with this

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_engage
BEFORE UPDATE OF response_json
ON engage_step_user_response
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.retakes = OLD.retakes + 1;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OF response_json ON engage_step_user_response FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.retakes = OLD' at line 2    0.000 sec[image]

Comment: What is the problem?  Some error message?  `retakes` is not changed?  What?

Comment: retakes changed before I update that query. But then I added  "OF response_json" to the query because i need to change retakes after update "response_json" coulmn

Comment: Please pist table schema

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my goal is to whenever "response_json" column has been updated the no of retakes increase by one. for achieve that i need to write a sql trigger.

Comment: @david_23 there is no OF keyword, `BEFORE UPDATE OF` should be  `BEFORE UPDATE ON`.  [CREATE TRIGGER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html).  For a complete answer please read [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and update the question